# OpenID Connect on Perl

Tags: perl, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I would like to implement OpenID Connect in my Perl web application so that I can [authenticate users on a Mastodon instance](https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/pull/16221) I setup against my existing user database. I've found various OIDC libraries on CPAN, but virtually nothing in the way of documentation, so I'm struggling to figure out where to begin other than reverse engineering the process that I use (for example) when my app connects to Facebook's API and building my own.

Is there something I'm missing? For example [OIDC::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/OIDC::Lite) and [Net::OAuth2Server::OIDC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OAuth2Server::OIDC) look promising, but there's not much to go off of. I've been trying to locate someone actually utilizing one of these libraries online to study how they're implemented, but come up empty handed.

Can anyone offer a starting point to work with?

Comment: Is your perl application running on the mastodon server?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Not presently, at least. I was concerned about putting Mastodon on my production server, so I spun up a VPS for it. Would you differ in approach based on if they shared a server?